# datetime and if statments with and

Tags: clock, shutdown

**
hi I was wondering if any one knew how to get my now.hour and now.minute in a if statement instead of adding them toutghter in times variable to get my computer to shutdown
example would be something like this in if statement instead
if now.hour==8 and now.minute==45:**
import time
import os
import datetime
#now= datetime.datetime.now()

def shutdown():
while True:
now= datetime.datetime.now()
minutes = now.minute
hour = now.hour
clocks = hour + minutes
if clocks==36:
os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
else:
time.sleep(1)
shutdown()
shutdown()

Comment: sorry here is the program right now

Answer (score 0):

import time
import os
import datetime
#now= datetime.datetime.now()

def shutdown():
while True:
now= datetime.datetime.now()
minutes = now.minute
hour = now.hour
clocks = hour + minutes
if clocks==36:
os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
else:
time.sleep(1)
shutdown()
shutdown()

Answer (score 0):

**Hi every one I figured out my problem and how to work stack overflow it works but it is in military time !**

```
import time
import os
import datetime


# one thing to note is that the time is military
#plus I am pretty sure I do not need my else statement
#because it will keep looping till it shuts down
def shutdown():
while True:
    now= datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.hour == 22 and now.minute == 31:
        os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        shutdown()


#calls the function to check the time and keeps running until it matches and then 
#shutsdown
shutdown()
```